# How to compute the height of $(xy-z^2, yz-x^2, zx-y^2)$ in $k[x,y,z]$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Firstly, how to prove that $\mathfrak{p} = (xy-z^2, yz-x^2, zx-y^2)$ is a prime ideal of $k[x,y,z]$? Then, how could I verify that $\operatorname{height}\mathfrak{p} = 2$?

Comment: It's probably worth stating that $k$ is a field or otherwise telling the Reader more about the setup for this.  It is often required to add more context to Questions that simply state a problem to be solved.  Why are these points of interest to you?  What results do you know that this exercise might be designed to illustrate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Who gave you this problem? The ideal is not prime.

We clearly have $\mathfrak p \subset (x-y,y-z)$. If the LHS would be prime, both sides would be primes of height $2$, hence equality would hold. But the LHS is generated by homogenous elements of degree $2$, hence the LHS does not contain any linear polynomials.

Conclusion: $\mathfrak p$ is **not** prime.

Comment: You are right. I found that $(x - y)(x^2 + xy + y^2) = x^3-y^3 = y(xz-y^2)-x(yz-x^2)$.